# Quando executo o cliente, o servidor encerra, porque?

Tags: java, socket

Assim que executo um Cliente a conexão do Servidor encerra. O bloco while do método run() da Classe Atendente não executa. Fiz um teste e o atributo executando está com valor true. Não consigo entender o que está acontecendo.

Classe Servidor.

```
public class Servidor implements Runnable{

private ServerSocket server; 
private boolean inicializado; 
private boolean executando;
private Thread thread;
private List<Atendente> atendentes; 

public Servidor(int porta) throws Exception{
    atendentes = new ArrayList<Atendente>();
    inicializado = false; 
    executando = false;

    open(porta);
}

private void open(int porta) throws Exception{
    server = new ServerSocket(porta);
    inicializado = true;
}

private void close(){

    for(Atendente atendente : atendentes){
        try{
            atendente.stop();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    try{
        server.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    server = null;
    inicializado = false;
    executando = false;

    thread = null;
}

public void start(){

    if(!inicializado || executando){
          return;
    }

    executando = true;

    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}


public void stop() throws Exception{
    executando = false; 
    if(thread != null){
        thread.join();
    }
}

public void run() {

    System.out.println("Aguardando conexão");

    while(executando){
        try{
            server.setSoTimeout(2500); 

            Socket socket = server.accept();

            System.out.println("Conexão estabelecida");

            Atendente atendente = new Atendente(socket);
            atendente.start();
            atendentes.add(atendente);
        }catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
            //ignorar

        }// no caso de qualquer outra execeção, a consideramos fatal, forçando o enecerramento do laço
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            break;
        }
    }
    close();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 

    System.out.println("Inciando Servidor");

    Servidor servidor = new Servidor(2525);
    servidor.start();

    System.out.println("Pressione ENTER para encerrar o Servidor");
    new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    System.out.println("Encerrando Servidor");

    servidor.stop();

}
```

}

Classe Atendente.

```
public class Atendente implements Runnable{

private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader in;
private PrintStream out;
private boolean inicizalido;
private boolean executando;
private Thread thread;

public Atendente(Socket socket) throws Exception{
    this.socket = socket;
    this.inicizalido = false;
    this.executando = false;

    open();
}


private void open() throws Exception{

    try{
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        inicizalido = true;
    }catch(Exception  e){
        close();
        throw e;
    }
}

private void close(){
    //tomando cuidado de testar se o atruibuto foi ou não corretamente inicializado no metodo open().
    if(in != null){
        try{
            in.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    if(out != null){
        try{
            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    try{
        socket.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);
    }

    in = null;
    out = null;
    socket = null;
    inicizalido = false;
    executando = false;
    thread = null;
}

public void start(){
    if(!inicizalido || executando){
        return;
    }

    executando = true; 
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void stop() throws Exception{
    executando = false;
    if(thread !=  null){
        thread.join();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(executando){
        try{
             socket.setSoTimeout(2500);
            String menssagem =  in.readLine();
            //Incluiremos a porta de conexaão do cliente para diferenciá-los durante a execução
            System.out.println("\nMenssagem Recebida do Cliente [ " 
                         + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName() +
                         ": " + 
                         socket.getPort() +
                         "]: " +
                        menssagem);


            if(menssagem.equals("FIM")) break;

            out.println(menssagem);
        }catch(SocketTimeoutException so){
             //ignorar
        }catch(Exception e){ // se alguma outra exceção ocorrer, forçamos o encerramento do atendimento
            System.out.println(e);
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Encerrando Conexão");
        close();
    }
}
```

}

Classe Cliente.

```
public class Cliente {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    System.out.println("Inciando Cliente");

    System.out.println("Iniciando conexão com o servidor");

    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",2525);

    System.out.println("Conexão establecida");

    InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(output);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        System.out.print("Digite uma menssagem : ");
        String menssagem = scanner.nextLine();

        out.println(menssagem);

        if("FIM".equals(menssagem)){
            break;
        }

        menssagem = in.readLine();

        System.out.println(
                "Menssagem recebida do servidor: "
        + menssagem); 
    }

    System.out.println("Encerrando conexão");
    in.close();
    out.close();
    socket.close(); 
}
```

}

Ainda não implementei as threads do Cliente.
Mas isso não importa para executar o programa.
Como resultado teria que apresentar portas diferentes de conexão do Cliente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema e após analise e teste do código e em resposta direta ao problema colocado, na classe "Atendente" o excerto de código:

*System.out.println("Encerrando Conexão");

close();*

Tem de ser colocado fora do loop "while" e o resultado será o esperado ou seja, na primeira conexão não será fechado mas sim irá aguardar por nova comunicação do cliente.

Comment: muito obrigado. Problema resolvido. Nem prestei atenção nesse meu erro.